# RegEx - remove line break if lines start with same string

Tags: regex

I have a .csv file:

```
ce3520, 3, 555420   
ce3520, 3, 555561   
vs5020, Manual, 554548  
vs5020, Ad, 1000382766  
vs5021, Manual, 554549  
vs5021, Ad, 1000382773  
vs5023, Manual, 554550  
vs5023, Ad, 1000382793
```

What I need:

```
ce3520, 3, 555420, 3, 555561   
vs5020, Manual, 554548, Ad, 1000382766  
vs5021, Manual, 554549, Ad, 1000382773  
vs5023, Manual, 554550, Ad, 1000382793
```

So basically, get code from each line (characters until first ","), compare them with next line's code, then replace with code + two groups. Like:

```
ID (.*?)\ 
ID (.*?)\
```

replace with:

```
ID \1 \2
```

I'm not that familiar with Regular Expression so I'm seeking help. Is that even possible?

Comment: It's really useful if you mention tool/lang you're using. If it supports variable length lookbehind and backreference inside, an idea to replace `\s*\n(\w+)\b(?<=^\1.+\n.+)` with empty. See [this .NET demo at Regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs*%5cn%28%5cw%2b%29%5cb%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%5c1.%2b%5cn.%2b%29&i=ce3520%2c+3%2c+555420%0d%0ace3520%2c+3%2c+555561%0d%0ace3520%2c+3%2c+555561%0d%0avs5020%2c+Manual%2c+554548%0d%0avs5020%2c+Ad%2c+1000382766%0d%0avs5023%2c+Manual%2c+554550%0d%0avs5023%2c+Ad%2c+1000382793%0d%0avs5023%2c+Ad%2c+1000382793&r=&o=m) (click on "context")

Answer (score 2):

You could match:

```
^([^,\n]+)(,.+)\n\1
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `([^,\n]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ chars other than a `,` or a newline
- `(,.+)` Capture **group 2**, match a comma and the rest of the line
- `\n\1` Match a newline and a backreference to group 1

And replace with the 2 capture groups, often notatated as `$1$2` or `\1\2`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JVczTN/1).

Output

```
ce3520, 3, 555420, 3, 555561
vs5020, Manual, 554548, Ad, 1000382766
vs5021, Manual, 554549, Ad, 1000382773
vs5023, Manual, 554550, Ad, 1000382793
```

Comment: And what if there's more lines with the same ID?

Comment: @freewheeler That depends, what is the tool or language that you are using?

Comment: If you are using `.NET` or the Python PyPi regex module for example, you can make use of the captures collection to match consecutive group 3 values and use code to do the replacement. `^([^,\n]+)(,.+)(?:\n\1(.*))*` See https://regex101.com/r/jliY6V/1 Else you would have to use a group 3 values matching all the repetitions that start with the group 1 value, and afterwards split the group 3 value on a newline `^([^,\n]+)(,.+)((?:\n\1.*)+)` See https://regex101.com/r/bySxZL/1

Comment: Unfortunately it's a built-in editor within an online marketing tool. No information on what language it's running on.

Answer (score 1):

### Match function

Possibility is depend on regex engine that you use. Like Python and C# has different engines so they has different syntax and set of capturing tools.

In c# bounded syntax I failed to create required expression.

Expression for python is not perfect:

```
(((?P<firstString>(?P<word>^.*?),.*?) {2,3}(?P<secondString>\n^(?P=word)(?P<secondStringWithoutWord>.*))))
```

It splits file to a matches that contains named groups 'firstString' and 'secondStringWithoutWord'. Those strings needs to be concated from code but it works

### Substitution function

It's more easer: just take previous expression and add substitute expression

```
\g<firstString>\g<secondStringWithoutWord>
```

So the result exacly that you need:

[image]

[regex 101 snippet](https://regex101.com/r/cJkQUZ/4)